# error running python3.6.9 arch linux

Tags: python, python3

i have`python3.10`on my main system ,
i installed `python3.6.9` from python.org  for specific projects

i am trying to create virtual env using venv

the command is : `/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -m ven projectname`

when i run : `which python3.6`
i get : `/usr/local/bin/python3.6`

but when i try to create the venv i get error ;

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f5cec284740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Do you have a directory `/usr/local/lib/python3.6` that contains a bunch of .py files?

Comment: You could try installing the python36 AUR package; it's on version 3.6.15, if that makes a difference. Another option is **pyenv**: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv